# Are these exercises okay for weight gain for an underweight person?

Tags: weightlifting, bodyweight-exercises, weight-gain, bodyweight

**NOTE: Yes I'll eat also, not only exercise :)**

I read many questions where exercises were mentioned for beginners to *(eat and)* gain weight.

- dumbbell squats
- dumbbell lunges
- dumbbell sit-ups
- dumbbell calf raises
- dumbbell step ups

Are these okay to start with? And where can I find guidance how to do them with dumbbells? **I know nothing about it!**

For example, for squat, I think it's just an exercise without any equipment, like sitting and getting up quickly! But I guess it's wrong!

Comment: Those exercises are fine, but your diet will dictate weight gain, not your training.

Comment: Do you only have access to dumbbells? How about barbells, kettlebells, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all of these are great exercises for beginners. All of these are listed exercises on Exrx.net, which is a long-standing and well-regarded exercise resource and directory used by many professional organizations and government agencies.

Here are links to all of these exercises which includes detailed instructions on how to perform them:

https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/DBSquat

https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/DBLunge

https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/RectusAbdominis/DBPushSitUp

https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Gastrocnemius/DBStandingCalfRaise

https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/DBStepUp

If you are looking for less clinical and more subjective advice on how to perform these exercises, you can look all of them up on Youtube as well.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly answering your question: No, they are not good exercises. Sure, you'll build some muscle, but you will also burn calories performing them.

If you simply want to gain *weight*, just eat a lot and stop moving.

But I don't think that's what you want. Let's assume you are skinny/underweight and want to gain muscle, and some extra fat wouldn't be the worst thing.

Those exercises are okay, but their barbell counterparts would be preferable. You can usually go heavier, which means you will build more muscle (a little bit tongue in cheek, but for you it will probably hold).

But as has been said before: diet will make or break everything. If you want to gain weight, you have to eat. Regardless of the exercise. And the more you exercise the more you will have to eat to counter the burned calories.